# Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollToM is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm using Karl Swedberg's Smooth Scroll v1.4.5 on a website. Only this version of the smooth scroll works, and although it works, I'm getting the error that scrollToM is not defined.

Also, whenever I navigate to a specific page by utilizing the script it keeps on adding

```
<div style="height: 101%; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

and the page size continues to grow, causing more problems.

Here's the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".contactLink").click(function(){
                    if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
                        $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
                    }
                });
            });
            function closeForm(){
                $("#messageSent").show("slow");
                setTimeout('$("#messageSent").hide();$("#contactForm").slideUp("slow")', 2000);
           }

$(document).ready(function() {
  function filterPath(string) {
    return string
      .replace(/^\//,'')
      .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
      .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
       if ($target) {
         var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
         $(this).click(function() {
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
           var d = document.createElement("div");
        d.style.height = "101%";
        d.style.overflow = "hidden";
        document.body.appendChild(d);
        window.scrollTo(0,scrollToM);
        setTimeout(function() {
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
            }, 10);
           return false;
         });
      }
    }
  });
});
/*! Smooth Scroll - v1.4.5 - 2012-07-22
    * Copyright (c) 2012 Karl Swedberg; Licensed MIT, GPL */
    </script>
```

Comment: Here's the website link as well. http://unitedasone.web1337.net/

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to be defined. It's used in that call to `.scrollTo` but there's no declaration in what you posted.

Comment: OK, I got it to work. [Haven't put it live on the website yet]

I idiotically used an outdated jquery.min file. After going on Github and looking the SmoothSlide version up, I realized that the script was compatible with another version of JQuery [1.5.2]

Link :

    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"

Comment: OK great. That version (1.5.2) is quite old however.

Comment: Not that well educated in JQuery anyways :/